# twitter get request keeps returning code 88 - "Rate limit exceeded"

Tags: ios, swift, restful-url

I created an iOS app that creates GET and POST requests from Twitter to learn about making networking calls in Objective C. I had no issue, but now, I'm trying to create the exact same app again in swift. At first there was no issue, but last night, I started getting this following response

> errors =     (
>                   {
>               code = 88;
>               message = "Rate limit exceeded";
>           }
>       );

According to the twitter site, it means that I exceeded the number of calls per the 15 minute window. This was odd because 1) I never experienced this with my Objective C app 2) I only made about 3 requests. It kept giving me the same message even after the 15 minutes had passed. I decided to wait until today (more than 16 hours later) and am still getting the same message.

The odd thing is that I changed the consumer keys and access tokens from my swift app to the ones from the objective c app. The objective c app still works, but the swift one still is giving me the same error.

Answer (score 0):

I found this issue - I accidentally created a loop by calling the function that made the get request over and over again, which is why the number of requests were getting used up very quickly